# getmaxyx() Error in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, pdcurses

This message appears when i run my program through Code::Blocks
[image]

And Here is my code.I am not trying to create something huge , for now i want to figure out what pdcurses functions do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{

  int maxx=80, maxy=54;

  initscr();

  getmaxyx(stdscr, maxy, maxx);
  printw("maxy= %d maxx= %d \n", maxy , maxx);

  refresh();
  getch();
  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am using codeblocks and I have just asked the same question on stack overflow. Of course I didn't find this post before asking my question. I am using pdcurses34. I really hope you found a solution

Comment: @Thomas Williams I know it's not allowed to have discussions here, but that was over 4 years ago, I fixed it by I don't remember how. I just answered you so you don't have to keep on waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's failing on initscr(), rather tham getmaxyx(). This looks like another variation of [the problem you posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366869/unknown-output-console-error-eclipse/22392390), where the IDE is giving you only a partial console environment to run in, as part of its attempt to keep things integrated. I'm not a user of either Code::Blocks or Eclipse, so maybe I'm off-base here, but that's what it looks like to me.

So again, try manually opening a cmd window from the OS, and running the program from there. (Or, starting the program from Windows Explorer should automatically create a console window.)